# How to prompt a password dialog when user trigger a job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup a Jenkins pipeline view. The are three projects shown in the pipeline view, `dev`, `test`, `product`. `dev` means the development build it is used to compile and run unit tests. `test` means to deploy to the testing environment. `product` means to deploy to the production environment. The trigger between `dev` and `test` happens automatically. But the trigger from `test` to `product` happens manually. Developers need to click a button on the pipeline view to trigger the production deploy job. Since deploying to the production environment is quite dangerous and I don't want it is clicked accidentally. So I want to add a password prompt dialog when any developer clicks the button. How can I achieve this in Jenkins? Is there any plugin allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use build with [password parameter](https://community.perfectomobile.com/posts/946796-using-jenkins-build-parameters):

> In order to create the parameters, open a Jenkins build job and check
>   the "This build is parameterized" checkbox.   Then, click the Add
>   Parameter button, and select the parameter type to add. Note, that
>   when storing a password, choose "Password Parameter". The value will
>   then be masked. The actual values can be provided in the
>   configuration, or runtime values can be provided when creating the
>   build.

You should add execution of your code checking the password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can find the `This project is parameterized` and I can add `Password Parameter`. But where can I set the actual password value?

Comment: You should add execution of your code checking the password

Comment: I understand this logic. I can check the password in the build step. It works by clicking the build on the project directly. But it doesn't work on a pipeline view. If I click on the build button in a pipeline view, it will trigger the build without asking for parameter input.